# C++ variadic factory with move semantics causes run-time crash

Tags: c++, templates, factory, move, variadic

I've created a factory that's using variadic templates and auto-registration. I'm having a run-time crash with the code below with respect to move semantics when invoking a constructor (a parameter is moved) when trying to create a type that has auto-registered itself - via the Factory.

Could someone explain to me what the issue is causing the run-time crash and how to correct it?

I'm using c++17, so if there are constructs I should be using, I'd appreciate advice (example code) on that too.

EDIT: the 'access violation" crash occurs when ~Base() destructor executes - however, the member "_moveString" is NULL when the Base() constructor finishes. So, the memory clearly isn't being moved correctly in the constructor and then something causes a crash during destruction.

EDIT: Compiler versions tested are: Visual Studio 2017 with "Version 19.14.26430" and "GCC 7.3"

EDIT: removed code version where 'Base::_moveString' was a 'boost::optional' to 'std::unique_ptr'

EDIT: changed code to ensure exact function type match and only have a single param that we perform an "std::move" on (which is the focus of the issue)

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base(unique_ptr<string>&& moveString)
        :
        _moveString(move(moveString)) // why is moveString empty here? Should have value "moveString"
    {
    }

    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void DoSomething() const = 0;

protected:
    unique_ptr<string> _moveString;
};

class Factory final
{
public:
    template<typename My_Type, typename... Args>
    static unique_ptr<My_Type> Create(Args&&... args)
    {
        unique_ptr<My_Type> type = nullptr;
        auto iter = GetCreateFunctions().find(typeid(My_Type));

        if (GetCreateFunctions().end() != iter)
        {
            typedef unique_ptr<My_Type>(*create_func)(Args...);
            auto create = reinterpret_cast<create_func>(iter->second);
            //auto a = (get<1>(forward_as_tuple(forward<Args>(args)...))).get(); // DEBUGGING
            type = create(forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        return type;
    }

    template<typename My_Type, typename Func>
    static bool Register(Func func)
    {
        bool isRegistered = false;

        if (GetCreateFunctions().end() == GetCreateFunctions().find(typeid(My_Type)))
        {
            GetCreateFunctions()[typeid(My_Type)] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(func);
            isRegistered = true;
        }

        return isRegistered;
    }

private:
    static unordered_map<type_index, void*>& GetCreateFunctions()
    {
        static unordered_map<type_index, void*> map;
        return map;
    }
};

class Derived final : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(unique_ptr<string>&& moveString)
        :
        Base(move(moveString))
    {
    }

    ~Derived() = default;

    void DoSomething() const override
    {
        if (_moveString)
        {
            // do something...
        }
    }

private:
    static const bool _isRegistered;

    static unique_ptr<Derived> Create(unique_ptr<string>&& moveString)
    {
        return make_unique<Derived>(move(moveString));
    }
};

const bool Derived::_isRegistered = Factory::template Register<Derived>(&Derived::Create);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string moveString = "moveString";
    unique_ptr<Base> myBase = Factory::template Create<Derived>(make_unique<string>(move(moveString)));

    if (myBase)
        printf("Success\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I'm having a run-time exception" Which one? Where? I'm not.

Comment: When it's trying to move the 'boost::optional' in the 'Base' class constructor... "access violation writing location". This is in Debug mode with MSVC or GCC. You can change boost::optional to unique_ptr and it will behave the same.

Comment: What's with the down votes?

Comment: Oops, I did use 'error' and 'exception' inter-changeable when I shouldn't have, I will correct this. Yes, it is a crash.

Comment: Did you try debugging it yourself?

Comment: Of course, I stepped into the code for boost::optional and unique_ptr... I couldn't figure this one out.

Comment: You can probably delete the earlier stuff from the question and just leave the MCVE without boost (assuming that does actually show the problem)

Comment: @M.M ok, I have removed the example where "_moveString" in Base class was boost::optional and now only have a code example with "_moveString" as a unique_ptr instead.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Runs without crashing, valgrind reports no memory violations. Given that, and the comments regarding `boost::optional`, which is found nowhere in the shown code, the most likely conclusion is that the shown code is not real code that's having an issue, but fake code; as such no authoritative explanation will be possible. But the most likely culprit in the real code, whatever it might be, would be the reference `refString` class member. Such design is fertile breeding ground for undefined behavior.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I removed the code with 'boost::optional' being the type for "_moveString" and left an example with it being "unique_ptr" instead (as per M.M. suggestion). The code above is real code that I am running in Visual Studio and I get the crash. This is for learning purposes of using variadic templates with a Factory. I have tried with both MSVC and GCC compilers.

Comment: Didn't show the problem with boost/optional and doesn't show the problem with unique_ptr.

Comment: @GreekFire does the code in your question actually  produce the access violation on your system? It might help to show the compiler version and compilation commands you are using, since others have been unable to reproduce the problem

Comment: @M.M Yes, here is the exception "Exception thrown at 0x0022EAC8 in FactoryTemplate.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x65766F6D." and it happens in xutility in "inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all() _NOEXCEPT"

Comment: @M.M the more concerning part, however, is that "_moveString" is being set to NULL when trying to move the memory when the Base() constructor is being called, which is invoked by the line "base = create(std::forward<Args>(args)...);" being called. Is the value "_moveString" set correctly for you after the Factory creates this object? or is it NULL?

Comment: In a similar vein to my earlier answer, I think `typedef unique_ptr<My_Type>(*create_func)(Args...);` should actually have `Args&&...`. Does this fix the problem? (if so I'll amend my answer, if not then update question as before :)

Comment: @M.M you got it! :) Thanks so much. You should put the above as an answer and I'll accept. I'm very happy... was struggling with this all weekend!

Comment: I'm suspicious of this whole idea as you just get silent undefined behaviour if a user of the factory doesn't provide the right parameter types and value categories ; there are a lot of ways this could go wrong and be a pain to debug

Comment: @M.M I agree. I was thinking of using this code to be more generic with my Factories in real-life scenarios, but after trialing this out I'm going to give it a second sober thought. Neither compiler was helpful to guard against the "silent undefined behaviour" I experienced. Maybe some good static_asserts could help here?

Comment: I'm sure there are other approaches that avoid the problem, I'm no expert in the area though :) maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/  would help , or searching to see if someone else's factory samples had a similar use case to yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map stores `void *` and you `reinterpret_cast` function pointers to and from that. The code that consumes the function pointer is:

```
 // Args... is deduced from arguments to Create()
 typedef std::unique_ptr<MyType>(*create_func)(Args...);
 auto create = reinterpret_cast<create_func>(iter->second);
```

however the value you put into the map was the address of:

```
static std::unique_ptr<Derived> Create(unique_ptr<string>&& moveString)
```

This causes undefined behaviour. When calling a function through a function pointer, the called function must have **exactly** the same type as the function pointer points to.  (Ref: C++17 [expr.call]/1).

- The actual function type is `unique_ptr<Derived>(unique_ptr<string>&&)`
- The type you cast to is pointer to `unique_ptr<Derived>(unique_ptr<string>)`

which is a mismatch on the parameter type.

When using a forwarding reference, `Args` is deduced to either `T` or `T&` (never `T&&`). The syntax `Args&&` produces either `T&` or `T&&`.  So the required change is:

```
 typedef std::unique_ptr<MyType>(*create_func)(Args&&...);
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look into this. I made the changes above that you suggested to ensure the exact same types (as per the C++17 ref), but I still get a NULL value moved into the Base() constructor for "_moveString". So, the value is not being moved correctly for some reason when invoked by the Factory method Create. More specifically, inside this method, "auto create = reinterpret_cast<create_func>(iter->second);" and then "base = create(std::forward<Args>(args)...);"

Comment: @GreekFire Maybe you could update the code in the question to show the changes you made

Comment: I just did. Hopefully I didn't make a silly mistake, my eyes are bugging out now...

Comment: @GreekFire Edited now to reflect code changes & fix